# htaccess deny all but thumbs files

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Im a bit lost with htaccess Files and regexp exceptions...
how can I make a htaccess denying access to files that are like : #.jpg where # is one or more digit?

```
1.jpg ->deny
25.jpg ->deny
74_thumb ->allow
22_400 -> allow
14254.jpg ->deny
```

I'm looking for the correct regexp syntax to differentiate the number only to another filename.
I've found out that this can be done with htaccess files and rewrite conditions, or deny with exceptions but can't find a concrete example of how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (^|/)[0-9]+\.jpe?g$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: perfect, simple and correct, thanks.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: of course, I just waited for stackoverflow letting me do it (minimum time...)